# How to securely validate payment and send product

Tags: vue.js, security, paypal, strapi

I am building a website for a masseur with VueJS + Strapi, and clients can buy a gift voucher.

Right now I have the VueJS part set-up with a Paypal payment gateway.

I am wondering how to set-up the back-end part and how to trigger the creation of the voucher.

What I was planning to do is send the response from paypal (onApprove) to the back-end and create a new voucher in the database then send it through e-mail to the recipient.

```
onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
                    const order = await actions.order.capture();
                    axios.post('myapiroute', order)
                },
```

Is this secure ? (if I use CORS to only allow my front-end's adress to make calls to the back-end API)

Is there a way to "bypass" cors or force the front-end to make API calls ?

Is there a more secure way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `actions.order.create` / `.capture` to create and capture orders on the client side if you need to perform any server-side actions (such as writing to a database or sending to a product) as a result of that capture.

The order creation and capture should instead be done from server-side code, with whatever backend you have (apparently node.js in this case; there is a Checkout-NodeJS-SDK available).

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

(Since you are using a vue frontend you can look at [this vue-specific sample](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/single-page-app/#vue), but change its createOrder and onApprove to fetch from your backend)